# How do I keep FireFox from “spinning” with a long-polling request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp, long-polling

I'm using the following for a long-polling request (this is a plugin similar to getJSON)...

```
$.jsonp({
  "url": url,
  "data": {
      "settings", settings
  },
  "success": function(userProfile) {
      // handle user profile here 
  },
  "error": function(d,msg) {
      alert("Could not find user "+userId);
  }
});
```

The request won't finish until either 30 seconds have passed or there is information to send (long-polling).

The problem is that Firefox is the only browser that will display "Waiting for URL..." at the bottom. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: you sure its not a memory leak in FF, also check to make sure its not just your DNS, are you using OpenDNS or something ?

Comment: It's not a DNS problem.  I guess it could be memory, but I'm not an expert on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the version of the jsonp plugin, as this is a [known and fixed bug](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/issues/detail?id=17)